# Extended interface implementation as a function's argument

Tags: typescript, object, types, interface

Consider following code:

```
interface IUserData {
    FirstName: string,
    LastName: string,
    Email: string,
    Password: string
}


interface IState extends IUserData {
    isSuccess: boolean
}

const state: IState = {
    FirstName: 'Jan',
    LastName: 'Kowalski',
    Email: 'email',
    Password: 'abc',
    isSuccess: true
} 

const testFunction = (userData: IUserData): void => {
    console.log(userData);
}

testFunction(state)
```

The code returns:

```
{
  FirstName: 'Jan',
  LastName: 'Kowalski',
  Email: 'email',
  Password: 'abc',
  isSuccess: true
}
```

The question is why does the function even accept the `state` object. I'd expect the compiler to at least throw an error that the argument type is incorrect.

Testing this, I wanted to see if there's a possiblity to feed the function with an object whose properties are a subset of original object's properties without mapping them to a new object.

In short, the desired output would be:

```
{
  FirstName: 'Jan',
  LastName: 'Kowalski',
  Email: 'email',
  Password: 'abc',
}
```

Comment: Why would it complain? An object implementing IState _is_ an object implementing IUserData, by definition - the extra properties aren't accessible via that interface, so they're irrelevant anyway. And TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime, if you want to actually filter out some of the properties you'll have to write _JavaScript_ for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd expect the compiler to at least throw an error that the argument type is incorrect.

The argument type is correct. `IState` is a *subtype* of `IUserData`, and so anywhere you can use an `IUserData`, you can use an `IState`. That's standard in object type hierarchies, not just in TypeScript but in Java, C#, and many others. (TypeScript makes one exception to this general rule: when you assign an object specified as a **literal** to something [`let x: ABCType = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};` where `ABCType` only has `a`, `b`, and `c`] or similarly when using an object literal for an argument in a function call, it warns you of "excess properties" — not because it's incorrect from a type perspective, but because it's probably, pragmatically speaking, a coding mistake.)

> In short, the desired output would be:
>
> ```
> {
>  FirstName: 'Jan',
>  LastName: 'Kowalski',
>  Email: 'email',
>  Password: 'abc',
> }
> ```

You're logging the parameter value the function received. Nothing in your code does anything to modify or extract properties from that object, so all of the object's properties (including ones from its subtype) are present.

TypeScript doesn't do anything to *values*, that's a runtime thing, and TypeScript is a compile-time thing (other than the small runtime presence `enum`s have). If you want to write a function that removes excess properties, you'll have to do that explicitly with runtime code. TypeScript won't do it for you. (And sadly, doing it where you get the property names from a type definition isn't possible, you have to come at it the other way: deriving a type definition from a model object that actually exists at runtime.)

Here's an example of doing that (I'm not *recommending* it, I'm just showing you how you can do it if you want to):

```typescript
const sampleUserData = {
    FirstName: "Jan",
    LastName: "Kowalski",
    Email: "email",
    Password: "abc",
};
type IUserData = typeof sampleUserData;
const userDataKeys = new Set(Object.keys(sampleUserData));

const testFunction = (userData: IUserData): void => {
    // Filter out non-IUserData properties
    const filtered = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(userData).filter(([key]) => userDataKeys.has(key))
    ) as IUserData;
    console.log(filtered);
};
```

Then this:

```typescript
interface IState extends IUserData {
    isSuccess: boolean
}

const state: IState = {
    FirstName: "Jan",
    LastName: "Kowalski",
    Email: "email",
    Password: "abc",
    isSuccess: true
};

testFunction(state);
```

logs:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Jan",
  "LastName": "Kowalski",
  "Email": "email",
  "Password": "abc"
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#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-xBOYJFJ4zJeAplKoNKndKYjLwTAZUPmrDY7I5nG5y06XW7Zp7orgcuh1RMHnMFktwH0Q2qgA)

Comment: Thank you. This is perfectly clear for me now. It's an interesting perspective you show with inferring the type from the object. Very instructive.