# Best way to omit keys/items from an extended type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type:

```
type Thing = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}
```

And I extend it:

```
type ExtendThing = Omit<Thing, "bar"> & {foobar: string}
```

Now I want to get rid foo through a method:

```
const thing: Thing = {foo: "hello", bar: "world"}

const transform = (item: Thing): ExtendThing => {
  return {...item, foobar: `${item.foo}-${item.bar}`}
}

console.log(transform(thing))
```

This prints: `{ foo: 'hello', bar: 'world', foobar: 'hello-world' }`

Anyway to get rid of that bar without being more explicit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642560/extended-interface-implementation-as-a-functions-argument/69642667#69642667 ?

Comment: TypeScript types only do type-checking. It does not perform any runtime execution. Therefore, you will need to explicitly write script to exclude `foo` from the final output. A script with type errors can still be a valid JavaScript.

Comment: I don't understand the "without being more explicit" part; on the face of it you certainly need to be "more explicit" than you are about your intents if you're not happy with the current behavior.  Like, you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9J93m); isn't that "more explicit"?  Or what am I missing?

Comment: I'm confused, don't you want to remove *`bar`* rather than *`foo`*? You've used `Omit<Thing, "bar">` on the type, so...

Comment: *"Now I want to get rid foo through a method..."* As I mention in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642560/extended-interface-implementation-as-a-functions-argument/69642667#69642667) (possible dupe?): Remember that TypeScript is about **types**, not runtime values. TypeScript can't remove a property from an object, it can only remove a property from the object's *type* as seen by TypeScript. You have to write runtime code to actually remove the property from the object (shown in my answer there).

Comment: return {foo: item.foo, foobar: `${item.foo}-${item.bar}`}

Comment: Just to regurgitate what T.J Crowder said. TypeScript will never change the behavior of your code, it can only give you type hints. You implement the code and when TypeScript is not able to infer the modified types, you have to tell it what they will look like. Just delete the property yourself, you've already setup the type hint for the compiler

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using destructuring to get what you need to construct the object as you desire?

```js
const transform = ({ foo, bar, ...rest }: Thing): ExtendThing => {
  return { ...rest, foo, foobar: `${foo}-${bar}` };
};
```